# Socket.io: client.on responds to messages for other clients

Tags: javascript, networking, socket.io

so i'm having a problem with `Socket.io`:

So in the server i'm sending a message to the client like that:

**Note that the snippets below are just simplifications of what i'm doing**

```js
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    // ... some computation here
    socket.emit('other message', computeddata); // Should only send to the 
  sender
  });
});
```

And on the client im receiving it like that:

```js
socket.on('connect', () => {
  socket.emit('message');
});

socket.on('other message', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

When the server emits the message to the socket, it should only send to the specific socket right?
Well, ALL the connected sockets pick up on it.

How can I make it so that the message only sends to the sender?

I'm a bit new to socket.io,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using different devices or just different tabs?

Comment: Different devices in completely different locations on completely different browsers

Comment: Can you show your server on connection code?

Comment: Yup I added it to my question

Comment: If this is a simplified version, are you sure you aren't calling `io.emit` (or `io.sockets.emit`) instead of `socket.emit`? If not you might as well add all the relating server code, including the requires.

Comment: Alright, I'll add the full server code

Comment: @code Alright i added the full server code.

Comment: Well, this certainly isn't trivial... I have a feeling that the message all the connections "pick up" may be another server message. Double check your client and make sure to label your logs.

Comment: I have triple checked almost.

Comment: Okay, this is edging away from StackOverflow... if you don't mind, can you create a sandbox with the reproducible issue? It's easier to debug simply by setting the code itself...

Comment: Do you know any platform to make a nodejs sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io

Comment: I can't manage to make a sandbox there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to fix the issue, there was a `io.emit` line that I somehow missed 3 times, that ruined the rest of the emits.
Oh god.....

Comment: Yep, it happens ;) I'm glad you fixed it. Good luck!